# Export to PDF every parcel in layer, maybe with bookmarks?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, data-driven-pages, bookmarks

How to create bookmarks in ArcMap, for example I have a shapefile with parcels (300 parcels) and I want to export to PDF every parcel in a page.

Can I do this with bookmarks or if not how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the data [driven pages tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s90000003n000000) in ArcGIS. You can point the tool at your shape file and it will automatically generate a new page for each of your parcels.

[image: DDP Dialog from ArcHelp]

It is then possible to [export](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Exporting_Data_Driven_Pages/00s900000038000000/) each of these as separate PDF or as a single PDF from the normal export map dialog.

Comment: i have another question. how can i make dynamic color for example parcels with number 1 with red color and the other with black color?

Comment: Given this is separate to DDP you should really post this as a new question to get a more detailed answer. But you probably want to display the parcels using a field in the attribute table: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s50000003m000000